# PostgreSql data not showing up in WFS connection in Qgis

Tags: postgresql, gis, qgis, geoserver

QGIS<------>Geoserver<------>PostgreSql DB (with geometry column)

My connections are as shown above.

Task: connect Qgis to PostgreSql db via geoserver such that polygon can be edited in qgis and should also reflect in DB.

Versions: geoserver 2.23.2, Qgis windows 3.34.0, geoserver hosted on OS Linux 20.04, Postgresql version 14.8.

The polygon geometry is stored in a geometry column in DB.

Problem: the data in the DB is properly showing up in geoserver(verified from layer preview) and can be viewed in Qgis when using WMS connection(polygons are displayed). When using a WFS connection the connection is established but data is not showing up. The feature count is zero and attribute in layer properties is empty.

Note: the whole table in DB is pusblished as a layer and the DB user used to connect to geoserver only has read access.(i know it requires write access also but it will be implemented if the data can atleast showup). Geoserver(tomcat) is hosted on a Linux system, PostgreSQL is a service from azure, Qgis is on windows(mostly windows 11).

I appreciate any suggestions and any general tips as i am new to this field. Thank you

tried different WFS versions 2.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.0 but no luck

Comment: we need to see what is in both log files and the actual XML being sent to GeoServer (look in the networking debug tab).

Comment: does it work with one of the demo data sets?